# Can i build and serve feature libs in isolation in Nrwl-nx?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

As a large team we are building an App which has multiple feature libraries and all are configured in the container app each feature team is working on their own feature library.

Now Assume, I have a feature library in my Mono-repository it has all its routing defined, with all dependencies required so now i want to build and serve it in isolation and not in my container app. So that I  can work on it stand-alone.

All these libraries are in angular with angular container app.

Is this possible with nx?

Comment: What do you mean by "container app"? Do you mean that while developping an app you decided to create a library and therefore the only place where you are testing that library is from the app itself and you'd prefer to test it in isolation? If so I'd say just create an app specifically for this library?